# MKMapView showsUserLocation and load custom annotations

Tags: mkmapview, core-location

We are using `MKMapView` with `showsUserLocation = YES` so that we see a blue dot and accuracy ring. We've also implemented `mapView:didUpdateUserLocation:` to capture updates. From this method we get the users location and use that to make a web service call, the results of which end up as map annotations.

**The problem**

As long as `showsUserLocation = YES` the method `mapView:didUpdateUserLocation:` is periodically called. We only need to get the users location at specific times, e.g. viewDidAppear or when the user touches a button. If we set `showsUserLocation` to `NO` after the first update then we lose the blue dot which we'd like to keep.

**Ideas**

One idea is to check the `MKUserLocation` value received by `mapView:didUpdateUserLocation:` against the previous value to see if there has been a change, if there has then do a check to see how much of a change before deciding to load fresh data.

Another idea is to use `CLLocationManager` and to manually place a user pin on the map, the issue with this one is how to simulate the blue circle and accuracy ring.

Anyone know any examples? Or have thoughts on how to tackle this?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Approach taken was to use the first idea. As no further activity/answers, and given age of the question this will be accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest idea is simply to ignore all callbacks after the first good one that you get.  Or your first idea to check and see how far the new location is from the previous is a good one.  Simulating the blue dot and the pulsating accuracy ring is much more complicated.

Comment: Thanks. I've gone for the listen and decide on an update then ignore the rest approach.